# Are there plans to add calendar and ToDo List Sync in UbuntuOne?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, calendar

Files, Contacts and Notes are only half the truth. Are there plans to add calendar and ToDo List sync for UbuntuOne?

If yes, which client? Evolution? Thunderbird/Lightning? Stand alone client like Tomboy?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, there are no plans to add any calendar or ToDo lists, so don't expect to see them in the next release.

Comment: What about 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

To-do list sync would be a cool thing for someone to add, though. The best way to do that would be to implement a desktopcouch backend for Getting Things Gnome; some work has already happened on that at https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtg/+bug/490042 and I'd love to see that work continued!